# How to create a distro with ubuntu as base with preinstalled apps, themes and restricted extras?

Tags: 11.10, iso

I wanted to give my friends a taste of ubuntu, but they are unwilling to download all these packages online. So how can I create an ISO with Oneiric as base with all the other essentials? I will not brand it. And I've tried Pinguy and Mint. I don't like them either.

Comment: This is not an answer but there are some serious distros that reaches what you expect, like the Ultimate Edition (http://ultimateedition.info) and the Israel Remix Team (http://www.israelremixteam.com), of which I am using the last one since almost 2 years ago and there aren't any issues and they have pre-installed all the software that you expect your friends to test. They won't need to install other than specific software for their needs. But if you wish to create your own distro you must expect an answer. I suggest you to give these a try and check the advantages of their work. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

## Novo Builder

> Novo Builder is a Debian GNU/Linux tool for creating your own up to date Ubuntu variants (only Ubuntu variant for the time being)

The previous de-facto tool to do this was [Remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/) but it has sadly been discontinued.

A [Novo Builder Tutorial](http://maketecheasier.com/build-your-own-ubuntu-based-distro-with-novo-builder/2010/07/02) should get you started up.

Comment: Does this tool still work in 2016?